# Jquery UI Tabs and DataTable

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, datatables

I am trying to display a DataTable inside a Jquery Tab that is loaded through AJAX.
When I open the page in a browser it shows fine but in AJAX case it is a just displayed inside the tab as a pure table. 
Is there something I am doing wrong or there is no possibility to do that?
Thank you for responses.

As requested, here is the code.
Loading libraries and CSS, convert unordered list to tabs

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                        $( anchor.hash ).html(
                            "Some problem occured." +
                            "Probably the server is overloaded" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Actual tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
             <li><a href="picklists.php?id=1"><span>Ready to be Picked</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="picklists.php?id=2"><span>Shipping Ready</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="picklists.php?id=3"><span>Picklists in Proforma</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="picklists.php?id=4"><span>Picklists in Invoice</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="picklists.php?id=5"><span>Picklists Shipped</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Then, picklist.php file that is loaded through AJAX. I will skip the code, just w=show the actual output

> > > ```
> > > <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> > >       <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
> > >       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
> > > <table id="rows">
> > >           <thead>
> > >               <tr>
> > >                   <td>
> > >                   Invoice no.
> > >                   </td>
> > >                   <td>
> > >                   Company
> > >                   </td>
> > >                   <td>
> > >                   Items
> > >                   </td>
> > >                   <td>
> > >                   Payment
> > >                   </td>
> > >               </tr>
> > >           </thead>
> > >           <tbody>
> > > <tr>HERE COMES SOME INFORMATION</tr>
> > >           </tbody>
> > >       </table> <script language="JavaScript"> $(document).ready(function(){
> > >  $('#rows').dataTable(); });
> > > </script>
> > > ```

If I navigate to the page directly - it is fine. If I load it in a tab then it is just plain table

Comment: Well... there is hardly any coding at all. I will edit my original post in a moment

Comment: try moving  $('#rows').dataTable();  from ready(.... into  .tabs({
   load: function(event, ui) {$('#rows').dataTable(); } or the tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { $('#rows').dataTable(); }

Comment: I tried this as well, so that my code looked like: $(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
     error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
      $( anchor.hash ).html(
       "Some problem occured." +
       "Probably the server is slow again." );
     }
    },
    load: function(event, ui) {
      $('#rows').dataTable();
    }
   });
  }); Still no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it was really simple.
This is what I had to change in Tabs initialization

```
$(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                        $( anchor.hash ).html(
                            "Some problem occured." +
                            "Probably the server is slow again." );
                    }
                },
                load: function(event, ui) {

                },
                select: function(event, ui)  {
                      $('#rows').remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

So basically two dataTables cannot exist and function on different tabs so in order to make everything work old dataTables instance should be destroyed

Comment: I'm running into similar issues but dont have the same ajax requests (all different PHP pages) and don't use the same table ID for the remove() function. Is your remove() function deleting the selected tab's table from DOM or from the previous tab?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you fire  `$('#rows').dataTable();`

You try to do it in `$(document).ready` but that's already come on gone by the time your ajax fires off.  What you probably need to do is put `$('#rows').dataTable();` in the callback for the when tab is redrawn after the ajax.

If its not working in load, then use a setTimeout to invoke it a second later and see what happens.  If it's still not working then put it in the success callback of your ajax options and use the setTimeout trick again.